# Moving to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens, salary, cost-of-living

I'm a senior project manager living in Farmington Hills, Michigan. My company is an automotive component supplier.

I got an offer from within the same company in the UK branch. I would retain my same level (senior engineer=project leader=not yet manager) in the sales division in Coventry UK.

I realize the salaries are different, also the taxes (I know they are higher in the UK, but not by how much), cost of living and exchange rate.
What I would like to know is:

1. What is the average yearly salary for a senior engineer in the automotive market in Coventry UK?
2. How much of a chunk of my yearly salary would go to taxes?
3. I investigated and the cost of living seems about the same (some things are cheaper and some others are more expensive) but in general terms, how much would be needed monthly to live in Coventry (family of 3).

Comment: "How much would be needed monthly to live in Coventry (family of 3)?"  I'm sure there are families in Coventry on benefits of around £10,000 a year - but that would be no sort of life at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what your standard of living requirements are, but your company could tell you what salary range this particular job is paying.
To estimate your main costs, housing and tax, have a look at www.Rightmove.co.uk and https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/tax-calculator/